# Is there a way to pass params to a Flask-Restless GET_SINGLE preprocessor?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

GET_MANY preprocessors accept a built-in `search_params` dictionary, but GET_SINGLE ones only accept `instance_id`. A `kw**` arg is passed to all pre and postprocessors, but [I've found that this is just for forwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331794/1402368), though this is somewhat unclear in [the Flask-Restless docs](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors):

> The arguments to the preprocessor and postprocessor functions will be provided as keyword arguments, so you should always add **kw as the final argument when defining a preprocessor or postprocessor function. This way, you can specify only the keyword arguments you need when defining your functions. Furthermore, if a new version of Flask-Restless changes the API, you can update Flask-Restless without breaking your code.

Is it then not possible to pass parameters other than `instance_id` to a GET_SINGLE preprocessor?

EDIT

Perhaps there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do: I have two models, `Foo` and `Bar`. A record in `Foo` stores as one of its columns a foreign key to a record in `Bar`. I want a GET request sent to `Foo` which specifies a value for the foreign key to return a single quasi-random record from the set of records in `Foo` with a foreign key of the requested value.

Comment: What parameters would you need to pass?

Comment: Just updated my initial question with an explanation.

Comment: That sounds like a search query, which would mean the GET_MANY preprocessor would be used, even if you only expect one result.  Can you post some of your actual code, and what you expect the requests to look like?

Comment: I was previously using GET_MANY, but things weren't working as expected. I just discovered this was due to my confusion regarding the [weird Python way in which arguments (e.g. `search_params`) are passed](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).

Answer (score 1):

As @1.618 pointed out, my particular use case is better suited for a GET_MANY request, even if I'm only expected a single item in response. I'm still unsure of the answer to my initial question, but my intuition is that that no, there is not a way to pass params to a GET_SINGLE request, as in Flask-restless they are only intended for scenarios where an item is queried by id.

The solution to my particular problem was to use a GET_MANY request instead, which I had initially tried but couldn't get to work due to my incorrectly manipulating the `search_params` argument and my confusion surrounding [how variables are passed in Python](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).